# Is there any C++ compiler which can issue a warning for a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, temporary-objects, const-reference

Given the following code, where `x` is a dangling `const reference` to a vanished object, and is therefore undefined behavior.

```
auto get_vec() { return std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5}; }
const auto& x = get_vec().back();
```

It seems like neither *GCC 7.3*, *Clang 6.0* and *MSVC* is able to emit a warning, even with all warnings enabled. 
Does anyone know if it is any way to emit a warning in these cases? 
Is there any difference between `const auto&` and `auto&&` in these cases?

Note, if `back()` would return by value, it wouldn't be undefined behavior as the lifetime temporary object x is extended to function scoop.

*Long story: I have a code base where `const auto&` is used as the default way of initializing variables, and for some odd reason these cases executes correctly using MSVC, but when compiled with Clang for android, every occurance results in a wrongly assigned value. For now the solution seems to investigate every `const auto&` in the whole code base. 
Also, in many cases the `const auto&` refers to a heavy object returned by reference so simply removing the `&` is not a solution.*

*One more thing, I'm responsible for the miss use of `const auto&` :)*

Comment: " For now the solution seems to investigate every const auto& in the whole code base" - or use values, which in this case seems like the obvious, and possibly more efficient, thing to do.

Comment: How would you realize by yourself if this line of code has dangling reference (only knowing function signature)?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: In many cases the const auto& returns a heavy object, and therefore it is not as simple as just remove the &

Comment: @Victor But not in the case you exampled. Choosing the correct type for a particular situation  is a basic programming skill - one size does not fit all.

Comment: Ouch, that kind of code is going to leave a mark.  I've made some code that also does not execute correctly using MSVC (VS2017 update 6).  MSVC also does not emit a warning or error.  +1 for finding some pathological code!

Comment: A compiler that could do that for any program could solve the halting problem. And that ain gonna happen.

Comment: @ViktorSehr since C++17 it is guaranteed that the "heavy object" returned by value will not have any extraneous copy/moves  . Your solution was viable prior to C++17 if you had to deal with compilers that didn't perform copy elision, but going forward you should be able to go back to that.

Comment: @M.M Clarified. In these cases the objects are real references.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is a simplified example. The const auto& fits both references and values and is "almost" a one size fits all, as long as it is not a reference into an object returned by value. And this is where I'm looking for help by the compiler.

Comment: Maybe you could adopt a naming convention for functions that return by reference

Comment: @Eljay In our code base, I think I also have some UB that cause our program to works incorrectly after upgrading the compiler. In our case, the problem was related to modifying the same object more than once in an expression.

Comment: @ViktorSehr As explained in my answer, you can mostly avoid the problem by splitting the expression in multiple statements (or having a function that returns the final value/reference as appropriate).

Comment: @M.M I would avoid such naming convention. In fact, I would not encourage the usage of `const auto &` when in reality an object is returned by value as it make it less clear in the code that we got a copy.

Comment: @Phil1970 I am suggesting using `const auto&` only when the function returns by reference, and to help out with this it would be useful if you could tell from the function name that it returns by reference

Comment: @Victor I still don't see why you have to have a " default way of initializing variables" - your posts have not made this clear, to me at least. It smacks of architecture astronaut  syndrome.

Comment: @NeilButterworth As const auto& binds to both references and temporaries (extending the lifetime), it is a way of indicating "give me the result, and only copy if necessary", and this should be default (see RustLang for example). However, as the question indicates, there are rare cases where an object returned by value in itself returns a reference.

Comment: @Phil1970 • ooops, I should have been more clear.  I was using the OP's code with MSVC but using an `Int` class which wrapped an int instead of `int`, and since `back()` returns a reference, the const& binds to something that is owned by the temporary and is about to go away.  UB or not regardless, it is just plain bad code and bad coding practice -- and the compilers do not emit a warning.  I wonder if Coverity would detect the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only thing I can come up with right now is to use CLANG with -fsanitize=address. But of course this will only help at runtime, but then you get something nice like this:

```
==102554==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000020 at pc 0x00000050db71 bp 0x7ffdd3a5b770 sp 0x7ffdd3a5b768
READ of size 4 at 0x603000000020 thread T0
    #0 0x50db70 in main (/home/user/testDang+0x50db70)
    #1 0x1470fb404889 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20889)
    #2 0x41a019 in _start (/home/user/testDang+0x41a019)

0x603000000020 is located 16 bytes inside of 20-byte region [0x603000000010,0x603000000024)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x50a290 in operator delete(void*) (/home/user/testDang+0x50a290)
    #1 0x50eccf in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (/home/user/testDang+0x50eccf)
    #2 0x50ec9f in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate(std::allocator<int>&, int*, unsigned long) (/home/user/testDang+0x50ec9f)
    #3 0x50ec2a in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (/home/user/testDang+0x50ec2a)
    #4 0x50e577 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base() (/home/user/testDang+0x50e577)
    #5 0x50e210 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector() (/home/user/testDang+0x50e210)
    #6 0x50db16 in main (/home/user/testDang+0x50db16)
    #7 0x1470fb404889 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20889)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x509590 in operator new(unsigned long) (/home/user/testDang+0x509590)
    #1 0x50e9ab in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (/home/user/testDang+0x50e9ab)
    #2 0x50e94b in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (/home/user/testDang+0x50e94b)
    #3 0x50e872 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (/home/user/testDang+0x50e872)
    #4 0x50e2ff in void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_range_initialize<int const*>(int const*, int const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (/home/user/testDang+0x50e2ff)
    #5 0x50deb7 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector(std::initializer_list<int>, std::allocator<int> const&) (/home/user/testDang+0x50deb7)
    #6 0x50dafb in main (/home/user/testDang+0x50dafb)
    #7 0x1470fb404889 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x20889)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free (/home/user/testDang+0x50db70) in main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c067fff8000: fa fa fd fd[fd]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
```

Maybe you have automated unit tests you can easily run as "sanizizer" builds.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly there is no way of warning on this. The compiler has no idea whether the referenced object returned by `back()` will outlive the line or not, and if it does, there's no problem (though I'd be hard pressed to think of a realistic situation where a non-static member function called on a temporary object returns a reference to an object which outlives the temporary object).

It sounds like whoever wrote that code read about [the most important const](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/), and took away entirely the wrong lesson from it.

Comment: Just to be honest, I'm the responsible one :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Most of all why does the `const &` does not work as the OP expected, i.e. that the lifetime of the returned temporary is extended to the lifetime of the const reference to it?

Comment: @DanielK. `back()` returns a reference to an element, not a temporary value. For this to be safe, the vector's lifetime would need to be extended; but there's no `vector const&` in the code to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Indeed, [clang V10 issues a warning.](https://godbolt.org/z/c3nT3Mvc5): "object backing the pointer will be destroyed ...". gcc doesn't. 
I understand that `back()` returns a reference to an element, however, isn't this element  a member of a temporary (vector) and as such the element could be considered  temporary itself?

Comment: @DanielK. "Temporary" is a [specific concept in the C++ standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime), one that does not arise when binding a reference to a returned reference. The compiler doesn't have the ability to round up all the objects which need to stay alive to prop up a particular reference, and extending the lifetime of every temporary mentioned in a line of code where a `const&` is initialized would be massive overkill (yet still be potentially unsafe). (1/)

Comment: @DanielK. Consider: suppose `get_vec` returned a `vector<int*>`, and you as the programmer knew that all the elements were pointers to global objects. Would you want `const auto& i = *get_vec().back()` to automatically keep the vector alive, even though it's no longer needed? And how is the compiler to know the difference?

Comment: Understood. C++ is a complex and elusive language. Just when you thought that there's a C++ feature that provides some ease of mind (e.g., lifetime extension of a temporary) it turns into a trap when used improperly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a code base where const auto& is used as the default way of initializing variables

Ouch. :(

> for some odd reason these cases executes correctly using MSVC, but when compiled with Clang for android, every occurance results in a wrongly assigned value

UB is UB innit.

> For now the solution seems to investigate every const auto& in the whole code base

Yes.

Just as you cannot tell at a glance whether a particular case is "safe"/correct, the compiler cannot tell simply from a function signature.

If it always had access to the full definition of every function, it would be able to warn you in some cases (and analysis tools like `-fsanitize=address` will do their best with this), but there is no general-case solution for the compiler to detect dangling references at runtime.

Also congratulations on the payrise you can receive now that the guilty employees (the author and the reviewer) have been fired, right? :)

Comment: Well, it's me myself who is responsible :/

Comment: @ViktorSehr: Actually don't tell anyone but I've been known to overdo it on the `const T&` from time to time.

Comment: The worst thing about `const T` is it's `const`, so you can't warm it up. Drinking cold `T`... Yuck.

Comment: @user4581301: Meh, cold tea, hot tea, what's the dereference

Comment: Innit is an interrogative, innit? :-)

Comment: @Jive: No, it isn't.

Comment: Then I don't understand innit. I thought it was patois for "is it not?". What is innit?

Comment: @JiveDadson: It is literally a contraction of "is it not?" but has since passed into the vernacular as a general emphasising term which may or may not be used interrogatively. In this context, it means basically nothing but sounds hip and groovy. Innit. And now... I'm going to bed innit :)

Comment: OK, keep your danged up-vote then. I still think innit is an interrogative innit.

Comment: @JiveDadson: That's likely because you are not a resident of England. For what it's worth, you got it right that time :)

Comment: If you figure out how a compiler could detect those dangling references, don't forget to update the Wikipedia entry on The Halting Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, for the above example, one would write something like:

```
std::vector<int> xx{1,2,3,4,5};
const auto& x = xx.back();
```

It does not make much sense to create a whole vector to keep only its last element. And if you have an expression like the above one and want to use a single expression, then you should almost never uses `auto &` to start with.

It the object is large, then you should either use move semantic or reference counting. So maybe you would have a function like `GetLastValue` that would returns by value a copy of the last vector value and then move that into the target destination.

You really need to understand what you are doing. Otherwise, you should use a language like C# where you need less knowledge about the internal working of the compiler or the exact language specifications.

As a general rule, I would say that you should not use `auto &` unless **you are sure** that you want a reference to the returned item. The most common case when I would use `auto &` or `const auto &` would be for a range based loop. For example, with the above vector named `xx`, I would generally write:

```
for (auto & item : xx) …
```

except if I know that it returns trivial types.